# Java regex check if string contains 1 character (number) > 0

Tags: java, regex

Say I have a String as below and I would like to check if at least one character is a numerical value greater than 0 (check for 1 non zero element number). Is there a way to do this without running splitting the String and making a loop etc.? I assume there is a regex solution but I do not know much regex.

```
String x = "maark ran 0000 to the 23 0 1 3 000 0"
```

^this should pass

```
String x2 = "jeff ran 0 0 0000 00 0 0 times 00 0"
```

^this should fail

I have tried the following:

```
String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
if(!(line.contains("[1-9]+")) 
    <fail case>
else 
    <pass case>
```

Comment: Like `myString.matches(".*[1-9].*")`?

Comment: RegEx can get pretty wild, but you should at least learn enough to be able to do the simple stuff like this.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann mystring.matches works! thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
```

This method does not take a regular expression as a parameter.You need use:

```
    // compile your regexp
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[1-9]+");
    // create matcher using pattern
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    // get result
    if (matcher.find()) {
        // detailed information
        System.out.println("I found the text '"+matcher.group()+"' starting at index "+matcher.start()+" and ending at index "+ matcher.end()+".");
        // and do something
    } else {
        System.out.println("I found nothing!");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Use `find()` of the [Matcher class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). It returns `true` or `false` whether a string contains a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) match or not.

```
Pattern.compile("[1-9]").matcher(string).find();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (string.matches(".*[1-9].*"))
    <pass case>
else 
    <fail case>
```

The presence of a non-zero digit is enough to guarantee there's a non-zero value (somewhere) in the input.

Comment: This pattern will cause you to read the entire string, which we would like to avoid.

Comment: @MatthewMarkMiller There is nothing in the question about not reading the entire string. The only mention of a particular implementation is *"without running splitting the String and making a loop"*.

Answer (score 2):

And a (possibly) more efficient way using streams:

```
s.chars().anyMatch((c)-> c >= '1' && c <= '9');
```